# Why does my meta rep not add up?

Tags: support, reputation

Perhaps I'm missing something (no pun intended), but my small amount of rep on SharePoint meta doesn't seem to add up correctly.

Is this a bug, a temporary measure, or am I crazy?  I know it's not much rep to worry about, but it's still strange.

---

UPDATE:

Thanks for the great answers.  Guess I should've read the [FAQ](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) first (isn't that always the case?):

> Reputation here is entirely derived
>   from the main website; your reputation
>   is the same here as it is there,
>   synchronized hourly. Votes here do not
>   affect your reputation in any way.
>   However, you can earn unique badges
>   here on the meta site.

My only previous experience with Meta sites was [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) which appears to be a full fledged SE site with it's own reputation (not tied to StackOverflow at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that there is no such thing as Meta rep.

The rep shown on Meta is simply that of your main account. Currently, your main account is at 128, which is why that's the rep shown here on Meta.

You can check to see what's counting towards your rep either [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2881/thechriskent?tab=reputation) (visible for everyone) or [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/reputation) (to audit your own rep).

Upvotes on Meta do count towards some badges, but that's the only benefit you receive… other than the thanks of a grateful community, of course!

Comment: Is there any point in showing reputation on the meta site then? It seems confusing.

Comment: @Alex Angas, @Dori I think showing the rep (regardless of where it comes from) makes sense on questions and answers, etc. But I don't think the User/Reputation tab makes any sense since it shows rep being added up that isn't actually applied anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I can't view your picture because it's blocked by my work's firewall, but I can tell you for sure that meta and the main site only sync periodically.  If you go long enough without any activity on either site your rep between the two will eventually match.

Additionally in my experience the rep you earn on the meta site doesn't actually "matter" to your rep score.  You can check your reputation page in your user profile and see how you've earned rep on meta over time, but it won't be reflected in your score.